# How to run this html-minifier from the command-line on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to run [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) HTML minifier from an Ubuntu command-line. 
But I'm getting an error when I try to do so.

NodeJS and NPM installs fine:

```
root$ apt-get install -y nodejs npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
npm is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Installing the html-minifier seems to work:

```
root$ npm install html-minifier -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/html-minifier
<... SNIP ...>
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
/usr/local/bin/html-minifier -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/html-minifier/cli.js
html-minifier@3.5.9 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/html-minifier
├── commander@2.14.1
├── ncname@1.0.0 (xml-char-classes@1.0.0)
├── relateurl@0.2.7
├── he@1.1.1
├── param-case@2.1.1 (no-case@2.3.2)
├── camel-case@3.0.0 (upper-case@1.1.3, no-case@2.3.2)
├── clean-css@4.1.9 (source-map@0.5.7)
└── uglify-js@3.3.12 (source-map@0.6.1)
```

I can see that the html-minifier is installed:

```
root$ which html-minifier
/usr/local/bin/html-minifier

root$ head -5 /usr/local/bin/html-minifier
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * html-minifier CLI tool
 *
 * The MIT License (MIT)
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
root$ html-minifier
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Why can't I run the html-minifier? What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ubuntu, `node` is called `nodejs`. Two options I can see

1. Edit the file "/usr/local/bin/html-minifier" and change `#!/usr/bin/env node` to `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs`
2. Add a small script `node` to start `nodejs` for you, or try `alias node=nodejs`

Comment: Or `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`.